What is the noun put after "out of" in this sentence "drink slowly, check for the pip and leave it out of ..."?
There is a pip in a glass of water and you want to drink the water only but you don't want to spend time taking out the pip.

leave something out (of something) means ​to not include something in something.
To express the above situation, I would say "drink slowly, check for the pip and leave it out"?
But the structure says "leave something out of something".
If I was forced to say "out of", what would the noun be put after "out of" in this sentence "drink slowly, check for the pip and leave it out of ..."?
Someone says "drink slowly, check for the pip and leave it out of the water" is wrong but "drink slowly, check for the pip and leave it in the water". But I want to use the phrase "leave something out of something" not "leave something in something".

It would be more natural to say "Make sure you don't swallow the pip".

My cousin is so mean! he gave me a hot dog but left the sausage out!

You misunderstand the meaning of "leave out".

"leave the pip in the glass", maybe. If you're more interested in what happens with the pip than in whether the drinker swallows it.

I am so sad. Everyone else went to the party, but they left me out.

We might say "Take small sips to keep from accidentally swallowing the pip".

As others have implied, you leave out something you should have included, or that someone else wishes you had included. It doesn't imply excluding something you don't want.

@KateBunting, the dictionary does not explain the phrase at great detail like you. How do we learners know how to use it?

@KateBunting - It doesn't imply excluding something you don't want Really? I told the tale of my mother's birthday party, but I left out the part about her getting drunk and hitting a policeman

@MichaelHarvey - True. How would you make the distinction? "You don't leave out something that doesn't belong there in the first place"?

As many comments have pointed out, a construction using "leave out" doesn't fit this example well. One reason is that "leave out" does need a "of ____" complement. It doesn't have to be explicitly stated if it can be clearly understood.

"Just tell me clearly what happened and leave out the dramatics." —leave them out of your story.
"Thanks for cooking me dinner! Please leave out the salt as I'm trying to avoid sodium." —leave it out of whatever food you make.

But as you discovered in your question, with the drinking example, there are too many possible and unclear answers to "out of what?" The water in the glass, the water in your mouth, your mouth itself, the glass itself, etc. It's possible to imagine a similar but different example where it might work better: "The rock band has very picky requirements for their snacks. Fill this bowl carefully with M&Ms, but leave out the green ones." Perhaps it works better because it has specified exactly what is going into what (M&Ms into a bowl); it would be idiomatically odd to talk the same way about the drinking glass ("fill your mouth with water from the glass, but leave out the pip").

Edit
It may be difficult to form a sentence in the way the OP wants.
We could say

Drink slowly, don’t take gulps, and don't swallow the pip.

Collins Dictionary sense 4 defines gulp:

gulp countable noun
A gulp of air, food, or drink, is a large amount of it that you swallow at once.
I took in a large gulp of air. [+ of]
He finished his tea in two huge gulps.


"leave it out of your sips" is an unnatural use of the verb "leave out" but "don't take gulps" is good.  "leave out" means to omit,  to overlook, to choose not to involve or consider or treat.

Thanks, @TimR.  I've edited my answer.
